# Graph colouring and maximal independent set

Tags: graph-theory

I am asked to prove or disprove the following statement:

Let $G$ be a finite graph with chromatic number $\chi(G)=k$, then there is a $k$-colouring of $G$ for which one colour class has size $\alpha(G)$, the size of the largest independent vertex set in $G$.

After playing around a little, it looks like it's true so I decided to try and prove it. Here is my attempt:

Suppose that $M$ is a largest independent vertex set in $G$. Consider a $k$-colouring of $G$. If all vertices in $M$ are of the same colour then we are done. So suppose this is not the case. Let $c$ be some colour used on a vertex of $M$. If we can recolour every other vertex in $M$ with $c$ then we are again done. So suppose not, then there is some $x\in M$ such that $x$ cannot be coloured with $c$. So $x$ must have a neighbour $y\notin M$ such that $y$ has colour $c$.

At this point, I thought I was about to complete the proof by saying "replace $x$ in $M$ by $y$", but I realised $y$ might also be neighbour of some other vertex $z$ in $M$ and so the resulting set would not be independent.

I'm out of ideas on how to fix this. In fact I'm starting to think the statement might not be true, but I can't find a counterexample.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but the coloring of the Grolzsch graph at http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~chang/cs203.f10/proofs6.shtml might be useful to look at. The independence number is 5 and the chromatic number is 4. There is a 4-coloring with a color set of size 5, but it's not immediately obvious how you'd get to it beginning with the coloring shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true in general. Take the following graph $G$ for example:
[image: graph]
We can see that the maximal independent set $M$ consists of vertices $4$, $5$ and $6$. (If one of the center vertices is in $M$, the four neighbours can't be in $M$, so $|M|\leq 2$.) We can see that $\chi(G)\geq 3$, because $K_3$ is a subgraph of $G$. Three colors is sufficient, since we can color the pairs $\{1,5\}$, $\{2,6\}$ and $\{3,4\}$ each in its own color. We see that all three colors are in $M$, and that $G$ cannot be colored with $\chi(G)=3$ colors in such a way that $M$ is completely colored with one color.

Comment: Haha I wasted so much time trying to prove this! Was quite surprised it's not true. Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't you and @Gawin mean maxim*um* rather than maxim*al*? $\{1,5\},\{2,6\},\{3,4\}$ are all maxim*al* independent sets, i.e. they cannot be extended.