# Finding Largest Mesh Network in a Graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

To find **largest mesh network** in a `Graph G` , I followed following approach -

1. Complemented the Graph G to `Graph G'`.
2. Used Optimal Graph Coloring on `Graph G'`, which means using minimum colors and no two adjacent vertices are of same color.
3. Now **same colors** in `Graph G'` means they are connected together in original `Graph G`. (This can be proved easily)

> It is possible that **two vertices of different colors** , can still be connected in original graph.
> [Reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143003/complement-of-graph-coloring-problem)

**Claim**: For every `Graph G` there exists an optimum coloring `c` such that At least one of the  *Largest Mesh Possible* in `original Graph G` will be of **same color** in `Graph G'`. By this I mean to say that even though it is possible that two vertices of different colors can be connected in original `graph G`, they will not be a part of `Largest Mesh of original graph G`. It will be unicolor.

There can possibly be many largest clique , but I want to prove that there exists atleast one such largest clique of unicolor

Can someone please give a proof or counter example for it ?

Update : By largest mesh in a network , I mean largest clique in a graph

Example -

[image]

We can see a unicolor `1-2-3` in `Graph G'` exists which is actually a clique of original `graph G'`. I am saying that there will exists at least one such configuration of colors.

Comment: @prudiiarca this is an extension to my previous question

Comment: What is a *largest mesh network*?

Comment: largest clique in a graph @prudiiarca

Comment: Clique means where every node is connected to each other. So largest clique can be a sub graph of graph. Or even the whole graph can be clique if every node is interconnected. A complete subgraph in short !

Comment: The quantifiers are important here. Do you mean: for every graph $G$ and for every optimal colouring $c$ of the complement, there is a maximal clique which is uniformly coloured?  Or do you mean: for every graph $G$ there exists an optimal colouring $c$ such that... ?

Comment: FOR EVERY GRAPH THERE EXISTS AN OPTIMUM COLORING C such that. The second claim

Comment: The first statement is easy to disproof.

Comment: Yes yes , I guess the second claim is stronger

Comment: Any guess for proof Steven?

Comment: It's false, so no proof ;)

Comment: Steven I have made edits now

Answer (score 1):

Consider the graph $G$ consisting of 4 vertices: a triangle plus a vertex $v$ with degree 1.  Then the largest clique has size 3.
The complement $\bar{G}$ requires two colours in each optimal colouring, and we can give $v$ the same colour as its neighbour in $G$. This gives a counterexample colouring to the question with weak quantifiers.

The stronger assumption is also false.  A nice counterexample graph is shown
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/684108/849372). (You should consider the *complement* of the depicted graph as counterexample for this question.)

For clarification: if the graph below is the complement of $G$, then it has only three colourings (all isomorphic).
[image]
None of them has the property that the unique triangle in $G$ has three vertices of the same colour.

Comment: Steven the example you gave can be done using my claim where all three vertices of triangle are colored same and the indegree 1 vertex is of different color

Comment: Yes, therefore I mentioned it is only a counterexample to the *weaker* assumption.

Comment: But then it isn't even a weaker counter example to be honest. It's just satisfying my claim

Comment: And even the stronger one I tried , it is again holding true on my claim.

Comment: Both are holding true for my claim

Comment: Then I guess I truly don't understand your question.  The linked graph has only 3 proper colourings, and none of them has the property that triangles in the complementary graph are uniformly coloured.

Comment: okay wait, I'll add an image

Comment: Steven [this](https://ibb.co/VLh4Dff) will be the complement of Graph you mentioned , I colored it and we can observe , one clique `1-2-3` exists of unicolor

Comment: You're seeing it wrong.  It's the linked graph that needs to be coloured, and its complement is the graph $G$ you are looking for in this question. Nevertheless: your colouring isn't optimal and it's not the correct complement.

Comment: according to you in how many colors can it be done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124389/discussion-between-anirudh-and-steven).

Comment: can you come back to discussion